# Weird Laravel 7 Database Cache

Tags: laravel, caching

Every day now I get a new suprise from Laravel 7.

Now it is with its caching.

I have an API that works correctly with the Database credentials in .env file.

However, if I try to do a Request like the below from another project:

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'X-Auth-Token1' => $request->get('token1'),
    'X-Auth-Token2' => $request->get('token2'),
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
])->get('http://api.localhost/ping');
```

It fails with status 500! And as the log says:

```
 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I run "**php artisan optimize:clear**" and it had no effect.

"SOMETIMES", read "SOMETIMES", if I run "**php artisan cache:clear**" it works, other times it doesn't!

If I hard-code the credentials in "database.php" it works correctly.

But it makes no sense hard-coding it, since it's not supposed to be shared in git repo.

I don't know what I am missing here!

**UPDATE 2020-08-25**

After some time I partially found what's happening.

Laravel will only clear the cache if on "production" so that a "config.php" cache file is created.

Otherwise, it will use the environment value.

Why it's not updating the value when requesting from another Laravel project using Http::get() is still a mystery.

I temporarily solved the problem by setting the development environment to "production" and running

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u try `config:clear` since this is related to configuration cache?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that it only worked for production, not dev.